# Search text file for tokens and return matches Java

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files, search-engine

I am trying to make somewhat of a search-engine where the user gives no more than 5 keys to search for in a .txt file and then return the the lines in the file that match every key given. I have split the string of keys from the user into tokens to compare with and right now I have stored each line from the txt file into an arraylist of strings. When I try to compare each line from the file with the tokens nothing is found, and I know it should match at least one.

I believe I am not getting matches because the arraylist elements are strings and the contains() method is trying to match the whole line to one token.

How could I separate the strings in the arraylist into tokens so I can match single words within the arraylist? 
Or is there a different way I should be going about this?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();


    String userInput; //declare a string variable to store the user search input    
    System.out.println("Enter up to 5 words you would like to search for along with the"
            + " file to be searched at the end:");
    userInput = input.nextLine(); //store the input in the String variable


    String[] searchString = userInput.split("\\s"); //split up the string into tokens with 
                //spaces as delimiters
    String fileName = searchString[searchString.length-1]; //get the name of the file and
                //store it in a string variable

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fileName)); //scanner object that locates the file
    scan.useDelimiter("\\n");

    while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
        fileList.add(scan.nextLine());

    } // while loop that adds the contents so the arraylist

    for(int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < searchString.length; j++) {
            int match = 0;
            System.out.println(j);
            if(fileList.contains(searchString[j])) {
                match++;
                System.out.println("match" + match);
                if(match >= searchString.length-1) {
                    System.out.println(fileList.get(i));
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("No matches found.");
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: If it's an hobby project the approach is fine, otherways use Solr or Lucene.

Comment: What is the purpose of `if(match >= searchString.length-1)`?

Comment: @vandale To print the line if it matches EVERY token. The "-1" is because the user puts the file name as the last entry from the user input and it should never match

Comment: You should be calling `fileList.get(i).contains()` instead of `fileList.contains()`.

Comment: @user3570931 Then you should place it after the the innermost for loop so all tokens have had a chance to match.

Comment: @vandale, then where should I declare the match variable because when I move it outside of the loop  I get a compile error because the variable was declared inside of the loop. If I move the declaration  out then it will not reset.

Comment: @Jeff outside the inner loop.

Comment: I moved it and changed the contains() to fileList.get(i).contains() and it works now. Thank you very much to all who helped.